# How to redirect to a page when tap local notification in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, prism

I'm developing an app with Xamarin Forms and Prism and I'm sending local notification with native API. How can I open my application in specific page when user tap the notification?

Here is my Android code that sends local notification:

```
 public static class NotificacoesUtil
    {
        public static void GeraNotificacao(Context context, Intent intent, string ticker, string titulo, string descricao)
        {
            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            var builderNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

            builderNotification.SetTicker(ticker);
            builderNotification.SetContentTitle(titulo);
            builderNotification.SetContentText(descricao);
            builderNotification.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_notification);
            builderNotification.SetColor(ContextCompat.GetColor(context, Resource.Color.colorNotification));
            builderNotification.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notification = builderNotification.Build();
            notification.Vibrate = new long[] { 0, 400, 200, 400 };
            notification.Flags = NotificationFlags.AutoCancel;

            notificationManager.Notify(Resource.Mipmap.ic_launcher, notification);

            try
            {
                var som = RingtoneManager.GetActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneType.Notification);
                var toque = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(context, som);
                toque.Play();
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error("OdontoWayPaciente_MensagemErro", e.Message);
                Log.Error("OdontoWayPaciente_StackTrace", e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my method to register types for navigation:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Login>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Pacientes>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Clinicas>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<PacienteEdit>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ClinicaMap>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LinkWeb>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Sobre>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Views.Android.PacienteAcessos, PacienteAcessosViewModel>("Android.PacienteAcessos");
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Views.iOS.PacienteAcessos, PacienteAcessosViewModel>("iOS.PacienteAcessos");
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Views.Android.Main, MainViewModel>("Android.Main");
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Views.iOS.Main, MainViewModel>("iOS.Main");
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<CadastroUsuario>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Perfil>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NomeUsuarioEdit>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<AlteracaoSenha>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<RecuperacaoSenha>();
        }
```

When user tap the notification, I want open Pacientes page. At this moment, when I tap the notification, the app not open and does nothing.

Comment: did you find a solution?